# Mock method which is called inside another method

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, powermockito

I'm trying to use Powermock to mock calls to a database. Here is an example of what our code looks like:

```
public class WrapperClass {
    public static SearchUtil searchUtil = new SearchUtil();
}

public class SearchUtil {
    public Record searchForThing(String thing) {
        // Makes a call to a database and returns a record
    }
}

public class TestableClass {
    public void runMethod() {
        // When this is called, it returns null, however based on the debugger, WrapperClass.searchUtil is a mocked object
        WrapperClass.searchUtil.searchForThing("thing");
    }
}

@PrepareForTest(WrapperClass.class)
@PowerMockIgnore({"javax.management.*", "javax.xml.parsers.*", "com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.*", "ch.qos.logback.*", "org.slf4j.*", "org.apache.xerces.*", "javax.xml.*", "org.xml.sax.*", "org.w3c.dom.*"})
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
public class MyTest {
    @Test
    public void runMyTest() {
        SearchUtil searchUtil = PowerMockito.mock(SearchUtil.class);
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(WrapperClass.class);
        Whitebox.setInternalState(WrapperClass.class, "searchUtil", searchUtil);
        PowerMockito.doReturn(new SearchRecord()).when(WrapperClass.searchUtil).searchForThing("thing");

        // When the below call is made, a new SearchRecord is returned and is not null
        WrapperClass.searchUtil.searchForThing("thing");

        // Calling the method that calls the searchForThing method, when searchForThing is called inside runMethod, it returns null
        new TestableClass().runMethod();
    }
 }
```

I know that the static variable and such is definitely not a best practice but right now let's pretend I can't change it. When the call that is mocked is called within the test, it returns a new `SearchRecord` as expected. When it's called within `runMethod` it returns null however the `searchUtil` object **is** the mocked object as per my debugger. Why does this behavior happen when the call to the stubbed method is nested?

Comment: where is `indexUtil` defined in the above code?

Comment: Copy/paste snafu, I'll change that to `searchUtil`

Comment: `SearchUtil` is also not being initialized in the wrapper class, given that the member being call is an instance method?

Comment: Also just a translation issue, I'll fix that.

Comment: Understood, but little things like that make it difficult for us to properly isolate the problem.

Comment: `@PrepareForTest(WrapperClass.class)` so that static calls can be properly handled.

Comment: I really butchered that, sorry 

Comment: Alright. until you have a [mcve] that can be used to reproduce the actual problem. I'll refrain from suggesting anything else.

Answer (score 0):

Review the following, which should behave as expected.

```
@PowerMockIgnore({"javax.management.*", "javax.xml.parsers.*", "com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.*", "ch.qos.logback.*", "org.slf4j.*", "org.apache.xerces.*", "javax.xml.*", "org.xml.sax.*", "org.w3c.dom.*"})
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(WrapperClass.class, TestableClass.class)
public class MyTest {
    @Test
    public void runMyTest() {
        //Arrange 
        Record expected = new SearchRecord();
        String arg = "thing";
        SearchUtil searchUtil = PowerMockito.mock(SearchUtil.class);
        when(searchUtil.searchForThing(arg)).thenReturn(expected);

        // mock all the static members in WrapperClass class
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(WrapperClass.class);
        // use Mockito to set up your expectation
        when(WrapperClass.searchUtil).thenReturn(searchUtil);

        TestableClass subject = new TestableClass();

        //Act
        subject.runMethod();

        //Assert
        //...
    }
 }
```

Note the flow of the test.

I would also suggest making sure that the argument used in the test matches the one passed by the exercised method because if they do not, then it will also return *null* because of the mismatched arguments/parameters.

Otherwise you will need to loosen the argument matcher

```
//...

when(searchUtil.searchForThing(any(String.class))).thenReturn(expected);

//...
```

You can also review [the powermock-mockito docs here](https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/Mockito) for a better understanding of how to use the framework.